# CloudFlare SSL Certificate Always Invalid

Tags: ssl, cloudflare

I'm trying to install a certificate on my original server, and I manage to do so correctly. However, the certificate is always invalid so it doesn't work when I go to browse my website. Does anyone have any ideas as per what is happening?

IE: I select "I have my own private key and CSR" in CloudFlare and use IIS 10 to generate my CSR. Everything passes fine and CloudFlare issues me the *.CER key which I then import. However, it is always invalid when I go to add it to my bindings in IIS for my site.

Comment: Are these requests going through cloudflare or directly to your origin server? To go through cloudflare, DNS for your site needs to be pointed at Cloudflare and the DNS entry in Cloudflare needs to be in "Proxied" mode i.e. orange clouded.

Comment: Yes, 'www' and 'http' were. However SMTP and some headers (EG: test.mysite.com) were not, but that shouldn't effect it because I was testing the root of the site (which http and www fall under).

Comment: Do you an error with the certificate that originates for your browser or a cloudflare page that gives a 525/526 error saying something like "invalid SSL certificate"?